# Reasons to not answer follow-up questions asked in comments

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users, help

I'm often helping new users with problems they have while getting started with a particular software. After having solved one problem, it is not unlikely that they run into another problem. The follow-up problems obviously deal with the same software, but they usually have completely different causes, and therefore should be asked as separate questions.

Nevertheless, users often ask these follow-up questions in comments.

I am inclined to not answer these questions (in particular if no-one else will ever be able to find my answer and benefit from it). On the other hand, I still want to be helpful, so I at least try to convince the user to ask a separate questions. However, I find it hard to explain in a short and friendly way why I (and potentially also others) don't want to answer follow-up question in comments.

So I was wondering if there is a good explanation somewhere that I could reference to educate the users? (And if not, could someone write one as answer to this question? ;-)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions :)